# If element changed class from one particular to another in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, triggers, slideshow

Normally my slideshow goes automatically to the next picture, but I want to detect if it goes backwards by an user-initiated action (keyboard arrows or controls). My solution to this would be to do this (my imaginary code):

```
if(jQuery("#slideshow article").hasChangedClassFrom("previous").hasChangedClassTo("current")) {
    backwards = true;
}
if(backwards) { // code for backwards
    jQuery("#slideshow article.previous").css("z-index", "1");
    jQuery("#slideshow article.next").css("z-index", "2");
}
else { // code for forwards (normal state)
    jQuery("#slideshow article.previous").css("z-index", "2");
    jQuery("#slideshow article.next").css("z-index", "1");
}
```

The classes are already implemented, so that the current slide always has the class "current" and so on. I know this isn't valid code at all, but by reading this, I think it would be quite clear what I want to achieve. I'm not very good at JavaScript/jQuery, but I've tried searching for solutions like this without luck.

[Live site](http://dans.no) // [Live JS code](http://dans.no/cycle.js)

Comment: when will you change the class to `previous`, `current` ect..? In the event handler triggered by *user-initiated action* right..? Why can't you do the respective logic inside it..? What is the point of   doing all this..?

Comment: @TJ There are 3 slides, one with a "current" class, one with a "next" class, and one with a "previous" class. This has already been coded correctly so that it would change automatically after 5 seconds. The user can also click to the slide he/she wants by clicking on a navigation or using keyboard arrows. I want to detect if going backwards, because the CSS `z-index` needs to be different when doing that, because of animations.

Comment: Can you provide an online demo such as a code snippet or jsfiddle..?

Comment: It's live on http://dans.no - the js code for the slideshow is http://dans.no/cycle.js

Comment: I know everything isn't perfect yet, it's probably bad code. I just did it, and tend to fix it later. But it is working to a degree

Comment: @TJ, are you still helping me? Or someone else?

Comment: Someone, please help me with the question. I don't think other code is needed for doing that. A class is already changed in JS, how do I detect if a class has changed from "foo" to "bar" - if you know what I mean.

Comment: Why do you want to know why the class has changed? Do you want to make a popup or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of guessing that the previous class, use the current and the previous index.

http://jsfiddle.net/whyba4L9/5/

UPDATE 2:

```
var stopp, antall = jQuery("#slideshow article").length;
var index = 0

function slideTo(idx) {
    jQuery("#slideshow article, #slideshow nav a").removeAttr("class").filter(':nth-of-type(' + (idx+1) + ')').addClass("current");
    if(jQuery("#slideshow article:nth-of-type(2)").hasClass("current")) {
        jQuery("#slideshow article:first-of-type").addClass("forrige");
        jQuery("#slideshow article:last-of-type").addClass("neste");
    }
    else if(jQuery("#slideshow article:first-of-type").hasClass("current")) {
        jQuery("#slideshow article:last-of-type").addClass("forrige");
        jQuery("#slideshow article:nth-of-type(2)").addClass("neste");
    }
    else if(jQuery("#slideshow article:last-of-type").hasClass("current")) {
        jQuery("#slideshow article:nth-of-type(2)").addClass("forrige");
        jQuery("#slideshow article:first-of-type").addClass("neste");
    }

    if(index ==antall-1 && idx ==0 )
    {
        //lasto to first
    }
    else if(index>idx || (index == 0 && idx == antall-1))
    {
        alert('BACKWARDS')
    }
    index = idx;

};
function startCycle() {
    stopp = setInterval(function() {
        jQuery("#slideshow article").stop(true, true);
        var idx = index + 1 > antall - 1 ? 0 : index + 1;
        slideTo(idx,false);
    }, 5500);
}; 
if (antall > 1) {
    jQuery("#slideshow").append("<nav>").css("height", jQuery("#slideshow img").height());
    jQuery("#slideshow article").each(function() {
        jQuery("#slideshow nav").append("<a>&bull;</a>");
    }).filter(":first-of-type").addClass("current first");
    jQuery("#slideshow article:nth-of-type(2)").addClass("neste");
    jQuery("#slideshow article:last-of-type").addClass("forrige");
    startCycle();
    jQuery("#slideshow nav a").click(function() {
        clearInterval(stopp);
        startCycle();
        var idx = jQuery("#slideshow nav a").index(this);
        if (index === idx) return;
        slideTo(idx);
    }).filter(":first-of-type").addClass("current");
    jQuery(document).keyup(function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 37) {
            var idx = index - 1 < 0 ? antall - 1 : index - 1;
            slideTo(idx);
            clearInterval(stopp);
            startCycle();
        } 
        else if (e.keyCode == 39) {
            var idx = index + 1 > antall - 1 ? 0 : index + 1;
            slideTo(idx);
            clearInterval(stopp);
            startCycle();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Hi, and thanks for your reply and help. I've updated my question with some clarification and live code. I'm just wondering, why not use the classes as they're already implemented? If the slide with a previous class changes to the current class, you will always know that it's going backwards. The code looks better in my head than making 2 new variables and new arguments. I haven't tested out your code yet, but I tested @AllwinP's code and it seems essentially the same - works partially except when the previous slide is the last one (3), and the current slide is first (1).

Comment: I've looked at your fiddle now, thanks. It has the same problem, though, when going from the first to the third. It would be fixed by using the already-existent classes, I don't know why nobody is using them, haha..

Comment: @SimenMangseth classes are not useful if you have more than 3 slides

Comment: Okay, thanks for your help, but your code in the fiddle still doesn't work when going from the first slide to the third. The third acts as the previous when on the first one, if you understand the logic in it, and thus, when using the keyboard arrows when on the first slide, your alert should appear, but it doesn't as of now, for me.

Comment: I'm sorry, I missed that part. Please see update 2. I hope that now finally works :)

Comment: Thanks, it works now - but is there any chance you might be able to delete the first if (the last to first)? I don't need it, and it clutters the code. But if I remove it, the backwards alert triggers when going from the third to first, which is in fact forwards.

Comment: Got it working by using `if(index > idx && !(index == antall - 1 && idx == 0) || (index == 0 && idx == antall - 1))`, thus excluding the first if in the second. Is there a more elegant solution?

Comment: If I understand you correctly: if you remove the slide in this if condition - `if(index ==antall-1 && idx ==0 )`, there should not be any problem with the trigger.

Comment: If I remove that if-statement, it triggers when going from third to first. I managed to integrate it in one if-statement, but just wondered if it was a better way of writing it, e.g. simplifying.

Comment: But if not, thanks anyway for your help, you've helped me a lot. I'm wondering about who I should give the bounty, and who should be the accepted answer.

Comment: I'm new here, but I guess you also accept the answer.

Comment: How can you be new here when you have 2000+ in reputation? I had 100 before this bounty, and I've been here for 2 years, haha (not entirely active, though).

Comment: But now I have another question for you, if you don't mind. You know the static previous and next classes that wouldn't work if one added more slides? Now they're updated dynamically: `jQuery("#slideshow article:nth-of-type(" + (idx > 0 ? idx : antall) + ")").addClass("forrige"); jQuery("#slideshow article:nth-of-type(" + (idx < antall - 1 ? idx + 2 : 1) + ")").addClass("neste");`. Can I now use class change (like I originally wanted) to detect the backwards code?

Comment: I'm not familiar with all the features of this website. only answer and comment :) Try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/whyba4L9/8/)

Answer (score 2):

Based on the code from the mentioned link http://dans.no/cycle.js

Declare a variable clickindex=0;

Place the following inside the click function of jQuery("#slideshow nav a").click

```
clickindex = jQuery("#slideshow nav a").index(this);
if(clickindex<index){
    console.log("execute some logic");
}
```

The jsfiddle link  for  my solution javascript code  http://jsfiddle.net/y601tkfL/

Comment: Hi, and thanks for your reply. As you can see in the code, the user can also use the keyboard arrows (`.keyup()`), will this work for it? The classes `next`, `previous` and `current` are already implemented, it would be easier to use them like in my example. If the slide with a `previous` class changes to the `current` class, you will always know that it is going backwards.

Answer (score 1):

Try calling this function when the user changes the image with parameter of `this`. I hope I correctly understood what you are asking. If not let me know and I will recode it. Also if the slide show is finished please post your html and javascript.

```
function whatever(this)
{
  if(this.className == 'previous')
  {
    alert('the user has changed the image');
    this.className = 'current';
  }
  else
  {
    alert('the user hasn\'t changed the image');
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your time and reply. If you look above, in the comments of the question, you'll find live site and code if needed. I don't think you understood exactly what I meant however, as the class change are already done in the code (poorly, maybe, but it works for now. If there's something bad in the code, feel free to suggest, too, I'd be thankful for that). What I want is some detection of _when_ it changes from "previous" to "current", and then be able to use it to in an if-statement when that condition is true.

Comment: Could you post the code for the event handler for the key presses and mouse clicks on the circles on the upper right of the image slideshow?

Comment: Why do you want to know what triggered the image to change?

Comment: The code is on http://dans.no/cycle.js as stated in my question. I have managed to figure it out from the help of dm4web and AllwinP, but thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

The dead simplest way to do this, from what I understand your question to aim at, is to put a handler on the index buttons and a method for tracking the current image.

Listen for slide change

```
var currentSlide = '';

$('.slideIndexButtons').on('click', function(e){
    // Conditional logic that compares $(this).data('whichimage') to currentSlide
    var whichImage = $(this).data('whichimage');

    // ->this means attaching data-whichimage="" to each of the elements, or
    // ->you can just stick with detecting the class and going from there
    // Either process results in isBackwards boolean

    if (currentSlide == 'prev' && whichImage == 'current') {
        isBackwards = true;
    }

    if (isBackwards) {
        // Backwards logic here
    } else {
        // Other logic here
    }

    // Unless the event we're listening for in keeping currentSlide updated is also fired when
    // the slide changes due to user input, we'll need to update currentSlide manually.
    currentSlide = whichImage; 
});
```

Track the current slide

```
$('#slider').on('event', function(){
    // This is assuming that we're strictly listening to the slider's automatic sliding

    // The event you attach this to is either fired before or after the slide changes.
    // Knowing which is key in getting the data you want. You are either getting
    // The data from this slide $(this).data('whichimage') or 
    // $(this).next().data('whichimage')

    // Again, you can go with classes, but it is a lot of logic which you have to 
    // update manually if you ever have to add or alter an image in the slide set.
    // Either way, you end up with the variable targetImage

    currentSlide = targetImage;
});
```

With any luck, your slideshow code has an API that will allow you to listen for when slide-related events are fired. Otherwise, you'll have to find a way of setting up, firing and listening for these events manually, either through callbacks passed in or by (eek!) altering the code and possibly unintentionally changing its functionality.

This *should* give you what you asked for. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: Hi, and thanks for your reply and help. I've updated my question with some clarification and live code. As you can see, the `current`, `next` and `previous` classes are already implemented (poorly maybe, but it works for now). If the slide with a `previous` class changes to the `current` class, you will always know that it's going backwards. I think it would be easier to implement using that, as I want as clean and understandable code as possible. I've updated my code with something like @AllwinP's code (the easiest), works partially, but not in all cases. Please help if you have the time

Answer (score 1):

You can add this line at the very start of slideTo function in your cycle.js

```
if((idx < index && !(idx == 0 && index == antall - 1)) ||
   (idx == antall - 1 && index == 0)){
   jQuery.trigger('BACKWARDS')
}
```

and then add an event handler for "BACKWARDS" somewhere else convenient (Maybe at the end of cycle.js?).

```
jQuery.on('BACKWARDS', function(e){
   //DO THINGS HERE
}
```

Comment: Hey, and thanks for your reply. I partially used your code making a variable instead of a trigger so that I could use `if()` and `else()`, and it partially works except when the previous slide is the last one, and the current slide is first. It would be better to use the existing classes. If the slide with a `previous` class changes to the `current` class, you will always know that it's going backwards.

Comment: I have updated the answer to reflect that edge case. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Thanks, that case probably works now. But when trying to implement the code I want to have there, I get console errors, and the slideshow won't work at all. The code now looks something like [this](http://pastebin.com/TSwHp1i3).

Comment: Could you maybe provide the nature of the error or a screenshot of the console showing the error?

Comment: The console error is `Object doesn't support property or method 'css'`. That's weird, I've used that before without problems

Comment: jQuery method `hasClass` returns either `true` or `false`. It cannot be used to chain. You should try something similar to this: `jQuery("#slideshow article.previous").css("z-index", "1");`

Comment: Thanks, I ended up using a backwards class. However, even with your new code, it doesn't trigger when it goes from the first slide to the third. The third acts as the previous when on the first one, if you understand the logic in it

Comment: Edited to include the new edge case. Sorry I should've thought of it earlier. In any case, the code should cover all cases now. I'm sure there must be a more elegant way to go about this but I can't think of any right now.

Comment: Thanks so much. I was hoping for an easier way to state this, but  this will do. Let me know if you find a more elegant way, as you say. Thanks again for your help, do you want to get the accepted answer or the bounty?

Comment: That's entirely up to you.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a plugin [**attrchange**](https://github.com/meetselva/attrchange) which I think will effectively solve your problem. attrchange is a simple jQuery plugin to detect an attribute change. The plugin internally uses one of the following compatible methods based on the browser to detect an attribute change,

- Mutation Observer
- DOMAttrModified
- onpropertychange

Try out below demo to understand more about how you can use the plugin for your need.

[Click to read more about attrchange.](https://github.com/meetselva/attrchange#attrchange)

**Note:** The plugin doesn't use polling so you can use it without any worries, however polling is supported as an extension to the plugin. You can [read more](https://github.com/meetselva/attrchange#latest-updates) if you are interested.

```js
$('#test').one('click', function() {
  $('#test').attrchange({
    trackValues: true,
    callback: function(event) {
      $('#result').html('<div><label>Attribute Name: </label>' + event.attributeName + '</div>' + '<div><label>Old Value</label>' + event.oldValue + '</div>' + '<div><label>New Value</label>' + event.newValue + '</div>');
    }
  });

  //this will toggleClass 'blue-background' every 2 secs
  setInterval(function() {
    $('#test').toggleClass('lightblue-background');
  }, 2000);
});
```

```css
html {
  font-family: Segoe UI, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
}
div#test {
  border: 1px solid #d2d2d2;
  padding: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.lightblue-background {
  background-color: #DBEAF9;
}
div label {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/meetselva/attrchange/master/js/attrchange.js"></script>
<div id="test">
  <p style="font-weight: bold;">Click anywhere in this box to Start the DEMO</p>
  <p>The demo is to simply toggle a class 'lightblue-background' to this div every 2 secs.</p>  
  <div id="result" style="font-size: 0.9em;"></div>
```

See the pseudo code for your case using the plugin,

```
jQuery("#slideshow article").attrchange({
   trackValues: true,
   callback: function(event) {
      if ($(this).hasClass('current') && 
         (event.oldValue && event.oldValue.indexOf('previous') >= 0)) {
         //code for backward
      } else {
         //code for forward
      }
   }
});
```

Comment: Hey, and thanks for your reply. Although this extension looks great, it seems quite too much to implement something like this for such a small thing. I also need to support only IE9+ and the latest browsers. You'd have to agree that this if-statement is easier for an one-time-case: `if(index > idx && !(index == antall - 1 && idx == 0) || (index == 0 && idx == antall - 1)) {} else {}`. But thanks anyway, I will of course vote you up as everybody else replying

Comment: @SimenMangseth True, If this is just one time case.. go with the simple condition. Thanks for checking out my answer.